# Kdenlive snap package can't detect any videos in my computer

Tags: snap, kdenlive

I am using Ubuntu 21.10. I installed Kdenlive using -

```
sudo snap install kdenlive
```

Now when I try to open any video from system, Kdenlive can't detect any of my videos in any of my folder. I guess it has something to do with apparmor. So what I have to do now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the snap package (`sudo snap remove kdenlive`) and use apt instead

```
sudo apt install kdenlive
```

In Ubuntu 21.10, `apt` hosts a slightly older version of Kdenlive (4:21.04.3-2).
If you want the very latest version, you can use the [official PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Ekdenlive/+archive/ubuntu/kdenlive-stable), with the following commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kdenlive/kdenlive-stable
sudo apt update
sudo apt install kdenlive
```

Alternatively, you can use the [appimage](https://download.kde.org/stable/kdenlive/21.08/linux/kdenlive-21.08.3-x86_64.appimage).

The appimage and the apt packages should not have permission issues.

Comment: Yes, I know these alternative processes of installation, my question is if there is an way to configure the snap package to work properly. If there is a snap package then there must also be a way to use it, otherwise why bother releasing a snap package?

Comment: @PayelSenapati Does it work after giving it permissions to access files? See https://ubuntu.com/blog/a-guide-to-snap-permissions-and-interfaces . Snap was designed to be used in IoT devices, but Canonical is force pushing it everywhere. Even former Canonical employees are frustrated about it. https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/orz1lr/alan_pope_left_canonical_because_of_snaps/

Comment: uhhh.. the problems seems not be with the snap package but my lack of knowledge about kdenlive, I tried, File -> Open, whereas the correct syntax is Project -> Add. Sorry for not sorting it out previously, anyway thanks a lot for helping

Comment: I love snap package mainly because of it's OS independent nature, it come as a total package and doesn't depend upon OS.

Comment: @PayelSenapati Feel free to edit my answer to add the workaround for snap packages.